# How to use the Gram Schmid procedure in this particular case?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I have to find an orthonormal basis of the subspace $V= \mathbb R^4$ generated by $e_1, e_1 + e_2$ and $e_1 + 2e_4$

I am familiar with the Gram Schmidt procedure. In this case I am confused due to the generators. How can I interpret them? Or how can I use the Gram Schmidt procedure to find the orthonormal basis in this case? Any help or tip would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be more comfortable with the GS procedure if the given generators were denoted as $[1,0,0,0]^T, [1,1,0,0]^T,[1,0,0,2]^T$?

Comment: I think I would. I was not sure if this was allowed

Comment: But it's the exact same thing. It's just two different ways to write it down. If you don't think it's "allowed", then use it anyways, and translate it back afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will use that

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{e_1,e_1+e_2,e_1+2e_4\}\bigr)=\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{e_1,e_2,e_4\}\bigr).$$So (assuming that the $e_k$'s are the vectors from the standard basis and that your inner product is the usual one), just take $\{e_1,e_2,e_4\}$.

But, yes, you can also apply Gram-Schmidt to those vectors.